# Getting error "Failed to connect to 192.168.99.100 port 31539: Connection refused"

Tags: curl, kubernetes, kubectl, minikube

I'm using minkube (kubenetes single node). I exposed a service and when I want to run it with:

```
curl $(minikube ip):$NODE_PORT
```

i get the error that said:

> curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.99.100 port 31539: Connection refused

I also try to run the container in Docker and everything was good. But in Kubernetes I can't run the application.

I know there are similar issues in site, but as much as I seen, none of them fix my problem.

Does anyone know what's wrong? or what am I missing?

(I must also mention that I am new to Kubernetes)

output of execute "kubectl get svc -n namespace" command :

```
No resources found.
```

yaml file :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
 creationTimestamp: "2019-10-02T15:25:18Z"
 labels:
  app: urbackup-v11
 name: urbackup-v11
 namespace: default
 resourceVersion: "195336"
 selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/default/services/urbackup-v11
 uid: a1c18360-a2bb-4de9-a25c-b0ffd45a20b2
spec:
 clusterIP: 10.111.173.217
 externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
 ports:
 - nodePort: 31539
   port: 8080
   protocol: TCP
   targetPort: 8080
 selector:
  app: urbackup-v11
 sessionAffinity: None
 type: NodePort
status:
 loadBalancer: {}
```

output of execute `iptables-save` command :

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.1 on Sat Sep 28 22:33:21 2019
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [21:3442]
:INPUT ACCEPT [16:3200]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [1510:295823]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [1510:295823]
:DOCKER - [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
-A OUTPUT ! -d 127.0.0.0/8 -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.0/16 ! -o docker0 -j MASQUERADE
-A DOCKER -i docker0 -j RETURN
COMMIT
# Completed on Sat Sep 28 22:33:21 2019
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.1 on Sat Sep 28 22:33:21 2019
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [64079:559675075]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [65202:547155125]
:DOCKER - [0:0]
:DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 - [0:0]
:DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 - [0:0]
:DOCKER-USER - [0:0]
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-USER
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j 
ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -j DOCKER
-A FORWARD -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j DOCKER- 
ISOLATION-STAGE-2
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -o docker0 -j DROP
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER-USER -j RETURN
COMMIT
# Completed on Sat Sep 28 22:33:21 2019
```

here , result of `kubectl -n default get pods -o yaml -l app=urbackup-v11` command :

```
apiVersion: v1
items:
- apiVersion: v1
  kind: Pod
  metadata:
   creationTimestamp: "2019-10-02T15:22:34Z"
   generateName: urbackup-v11-774ff76465-
   labels:
    app: urbackup-v11
    pod-template-hash: 774ff76465
   name: urbackup-v11-774ff76465-ch42z
   namespace: default
   ownerReferences:
   - apiVersion: apps/v1
     blockOwnerDeletion: true
     controller: true
     kind: ReplicaSet
     name: urbackup-v11-774ff76465
     uid: 6d7ba6c6-5318-4dc1-bfd7-356f85598236
    resourceVersion: "212488"
    selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/urbackup-v11-774ff76465-ch42z
    uid: 22674f75-4507-4405-81d9-d1bb29b5a70b
  spec:
   containers:
   - image: uroni/urbackup-server
     imagePullPolicy: Always
     name: urbackup-server
     resources: {}
     terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
     terminationMessagePolicy: File
     volumeMounts:
     - mountPath: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount
       name: default-token-rggcc
       readOnly: true
    dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
    enableServiceLinks: true
    nodeName: minikube
    priority: 0
    restartPolicy: Always
    schedulerName: default-scheduler
    securityContext: {}
    serviceAccount: default
    serviceAccountName: default
    terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
    tolerations:
    - effect: NoExecute
      key: node.kubernetes.io/not-ready
      operator: Exists
      tolerationSeconds: 300
    - effect: NoExecute
      key: node.kubernetes.io/unreachable
      operator: Exists
      tolerationSeconds: 300
    volumes:
    - name: default-token-rggcc
      secret:
       defaultMode: 420
        secretName: default-token-rggcc
   status:
    conditions:
    - lastProbeTime: null
      lastTransitionTime: "2019-10-02T15:22:34Z"
      status: "True"
      type: Initialized
    - lastProbeTime: null
      lastTransitionTime: "2019-10-05T09:44:00Z"
      message: 'containers with unready status: [urbackup-server]'
      reason: ContainersNotReady
      status: "False"
      type: Ready
    - lastProbeTime: null
      lastTransitionTime: "2019-10-05T09:44:00Z"
      message: 'containers with unready status: [urbackup-server]'
      reason: ContainersNotReady
      status: "False"
      type: ContainersReady
    - lastProbeTime: null
      lastTransitionTime: "2019-10-02T15:22:34Z"
      status: "True"
      type: PodScheduled
     containerStatuses:
     - containerID: docker://ba3170190d5315e9edaa5e2674d5cd38bff6c8fd5c8025537a7c0ece77a695c7
       image: uroni/urbackup-server:latest
       imageID: docker-pullable://uroni/urbackup-server@sha256:ed18b99ac85147e01dceb2dc45844c5689fb19bbe4c915d7e5b52b6a376db242
       lastState: {}
       name: urbackup-server
       ready: false
       restartCount: 1
       state:
       terminated:
        containerID: docker://ba3170190d5315e9edaa5e2674d5cd38bff6c8fd5c8025537a7c0ece77a695c7
        exitCode: 255
        finishedAt: "2019-10-05T09:43:09Z"
        reason: Error
        startedAt: "2019-10-04T12:11:01Z"
      hostIP: 10.0.2.15
      phase: Running
      qosClass: BestEffort
      startTime: "2019-10-02T15:22:34Z"
kind: List
metadata:
 resourceVersion: ""
 selfLink: ""
```

Comment: Please mention how you exposed your k8s service, provide some yaml.

Comment: From error it clearly seems service is not getting exposed, also provide output of `kubectl get svc -n namespace`

Comment: Please share `iptables-save` output along with `kubectl get svc -o yaml <you_service>`

Comment: @mchawre , i used an existing image from github . i expose it with this command : kubectl expose deployment/<deployment name> --type="NodePort" --port=8080.

Comment: @prometherion is that what you mean?

Comment: Hi sol, your posted YAML says `- nodePort: 31229` but your `curl` says `port 32260`, so it appears to be a simple typo

Comment: @sol I was pointing to `iptables-save` of Minikube, not your host machine :) However, @matthew-l-daniel pointed to the right solution: you got a typo on your cURL port!

Comment: @sol let us know if changing port number resolve the problem.

Comment: @MatthewLDaniel , after i asked the question , i created a new deployment and actually the yaml file is belong to the new one . but the port number in the error that i always get , is the same with node port on yaml file .

Comment: @prometherion am ... sorry i know i sound clumsy , but .... i installl the minikube on my host machine. i mean the only nod that created , is on my own machine . so i run the "iptables-save" command on my own system . is somewhere else or another format of the command that i supposed to use?

Comment: @abielak as i said above , the ports are same . i updated the yaml file and the error

Comment: In that case, it's possible your `Service` selector does not match any pods, or those pods are listening on the wrong port; can you please update your question with the output from `kubectl -n default get pods -o yaml -l app=urbackup-v11`

Comment: @MatthewLDaniel yeah sure . post updated

Comment: Your `PodSpec` is missing a declaration of the [`ports:`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.16/#containerport-v1-core) it exposes to the outside world

Comment: @MatthewLDaniel am .... what should i do?! i am totally new in this case!

Comment: Please check documentation to see where 'ports' ale placed: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/connect-applications-service/ , https://matthewpalmer.net/kubernetes-app-developer/articles/kubernetes-ports-targetport-nodeport-service.html

Answer (score 0):

The [`ports`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.16/#containerport-v1-core) configuration is missing in your Pod `spec.containers`.

You need to add it and ensure that it matches with your Service `targetPort` (See: [Exposing pods to the cluster](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/connect-applications-service/#exposing-pods-to-the-cluster)).

It should be something like this:

```
  spec:
   containers:
   - image: uroni/urbackup-server
     imagePullPolicy: Always
     ports:
     - containerPort: 8080
     name: urbackup-server
     resources: {}
     terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
     terminationMessagePolicy: File
     volumeMounts:
     - mountPath: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount
       name: default-token-rggcc
       readOnly: true
```